# Swift 5.2 UIAccessibility.isAssistiveTouchRunning never returns true nor does UIAccessibility.assistiveTouchStatusDidChangeNotification get triggered

Tags: swift, uiaccessibility

I would like to know if AssistiveTouch is enabled or not, because my App wants to give the user instructions how to set it up properly for a certain use case.

I tried getting `UIAccessibility.isAssistiveTouchRunning` but it never returns true. I even put it in a timer and switched AssistiveTouch on and off but it always returns false. I then added `UIAccessibility.assistiveTouchStatusDidChangeNotification` like so:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIAccessibility.assistiveTouchStatusDidChangeNotification, object: self, queue: OperationQueue.current, using: { notification in
    print(notification)
})
```

but this never gets triggered.

What am I missing? Is this feature not available?

Greetings krjw

**EDIT 1**

I tried `isVoiceOverRunning` and it works. I can't seem to get further with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered same behaviour. I've opened a TSI with Apple and as for their response - It only works if Guided Access is also turned on and active. I'm trying to figure out if there's any way we can determine if only assistive touch is running. Will update ...

***UPDATE***

Apple has responded that in order for it to work, the settings option "GUIDED ACCESS" has to be also enabled. Which makes no sense as there's no relation between the two features.....

I'll send a feedback via Feedback Assistant and request an option to know if ONLY assistive touch is running.